# Error: Initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

Tags: c++, arrays

below is my code which processes the payload[] array and store it's result on myFinalShellcode[] array.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char payload[] = { 0xf0,0xe8,0xc8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x41,0x51,0x41,0x50,0x52,0x51,0x56,0x48,0x31 };
constexpr int length = 891;
constexpr int number_of_chunks = 5;
constexpr int chunk_size = length / number_of_chunks;
constexpr int remaining_bytes = length % number_of_chunks;
constexpr int size_after = length * 2;

unsigned char* restore_original(unsigned char* high_ent_payload)
{
    constexpr int payload_size = (size_after + 1) / 2;
    unsigned char low_entropy_payload_holder[size_after] = { 0 };
    memcpy_s(low_entropy_payload_holder, sizeof low_entropy_payload_holder, high_ent_payload, size_after);
    unsigned char restored_payload[payload_size] = { 0 };
    int offset_payload_after = 0;
    int offset_payload = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < chunk_size; j++)
        {
            restored_payload[offset_payload] = low_entropy_payload_holder[offset_payload_after];
            offset_payload_after++;
            offset_payload++;
        }
        for (size_t k = 0; k < chunk_size; k++)
        {
            offset_payload_after++;
        }
    }
    if (remaining_bytes)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof remaining_bytes; i++)
        {
            restored_payload[offset_payload++] = high_ent_payload[offset_payload_after++];
        }
    }
    return restored_payload;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char shellcode[] = restore_original(payload);
}
```

I get the following error on the last code line (inside main function):
`Error: Initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object`

I tried to change anything on the array itself (seems like they might be the problem). I would highly appreciate your help as this is a part of my personal research :)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, the error is in the line inside main() function: ```unsigned char shellcode[] = restore_original(payload);```

Answer (score 2):

In order to initialize an array defined with `[]`, you must supply a list of values enclosed with `{}`, exactly as the error message says.
E.g.:

```
unsigned char shellcode[] = {1,2,3};
```

You can change `shellcode` to be a pointer if you want to assign it the output from `restore_original`:

```
unsigned char* shellcode = restore_original(payload);
```

**Update:**
As you can see in [@heapunderrun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72424388/error-initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object/72424436#comment127942980_72424436), there is another problem in your code. `restore_original` returns a pointer to a local variable, which is not valid when the function returns (a dangling pointer).
In order to fix this, `restore_original` should allocate memory on the heap using new. This allocation has to be freed eventually, when you are done with `shellcode`.

**However** - although you can make it work this way, I highly recomend you to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic arrays allocated on the heap. It will save you the need to manually manage the memory allocations/deallocations, as well as other advantages.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the error, however I get a "Runtime-Check failure" from the Runtime Library: **Stack around the variable 'restored_payload' was corrupted.**
I guess it has to be with the code logic flow...
According to your recommendation, I just changed this:
```cpp
int main() {
    unsigned char* shellcode = restore_original(payload);
}
```

Comment: But then it would be a dangling pointer because that function returns address of a local array.

Comment: @heapunderrun you are right. My bad - it didn't look thoroughly into the implementation of `restore_original`. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a `char *` to a `char []`. You can probably do something with constexpr but I'm suspecting an XY problem here.